# How to display activity without click on notification when application is not running or Background

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using this code I display activity without click on notification.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);


        String imageUrl = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getNotification().getImageUrl());
        String title = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        String message = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FullScreenActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("image_url", imageUrl);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I write the code for display activity without click on notification but when app is running state but I want when app is not running state(Like Truecaller notification).

Comment: Never say "like XXX".  Explain what XXX is.  The majority of people don't know what a Truecaller is, much less what's special about their notification.

Comment: Also, it is not possible on modern versions of Android to launch an Activity from the background like this.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts